# Angular UI-Router very basic example is not working ? Please see full code on plunker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular UI-Router is not working? Please see my code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lF4ewH?p=preview).

I am trying to run a very basic routing example in angular js. But `welcomeView.html` is not appearing on the page.

```
(function() {
  "use strict"
  var app = angular.module("plunker", ["ui.router"]);

  app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "welcomeView.html"
        })
    }
  ]);
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [updated and working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBWPpEpornAKI4v3mePf?p=preview)

Firstly we need to add reference to **`app.js`** with our module

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="app.js"></script> // was missing
  <script src="script.js"></script> 
 </head>
```

Also, we should not use `ng-controller`, we do not need is with `UI-Router`

```
//<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<body>
```

The **`app.js`** on the other hand, should contain `controller : "..."`

```
  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "welcomeView.html",
      // declare it here
      controller: "MainCtrl",
    })
```

Then, in **`script.js`**, we cannot redefine the module plunker *(using setter)* - we have to just take it *(using getter)*

```
// this would redefine the app.js stuff
//var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
// just a getter to get that module
var app = angular.module('plunker');

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

});
```

check that all in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBWPpEpornAKI4v3mePf?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot now its working in plunker, but I don't know why its not working in my project i am using web storm editor.

Comment: I see, but that is mostly up to you. I cannot check your local stuff. You should observe all the single change I made, to make it running. And reapply it locally. Honestly this way I dived into UI-Router as well...

Comment: If i use different version of angular with UI-router will it cause any issue ?But at last now i am able to use UI router thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why would not you use the latest version? I strongly suggest to do that. There is no other way in longer run. Always up to date. So, does my answer helped? Solved?

Comment: Yes as you suggested i made all the changes in my project and it is running fine without any issue.